# Set a range in sizeslider: Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I use in my work program on the forum, but testing it I noticed that it works badly. As you can see in the attached image, the set size range shows incorrect fields in the table. Only when we select "**Choose Cat 1**" as "**all**" size range work well. Can you indicate what needs to be corrected?

[image]

Below is the code:

```
library(shiny) 
data.input <- data.frame(
  Category1 = rep(letters[1:3],each=15),
  Info = paste("Text info", 1:45),
  Category2 = sample(letters[15:20], 45, replace = T),
  Size = sample(1:100, 45),
  MoreStuff = paste("More Stuff", 1:45)
)
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectizeInput(
                      "show_vars",
                      "Columns to show:",
                      choices = colnames(data.input),
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = c("Category1", "Info", "Category2")
                    ),
                    actionButton("button", "An action button"),
                    uiOutput("category1"),
                    uiOutput("category2"),
                    uiOutput("sizeslider")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data.react <- eventReactive(input$button, {
    data.input[, input$show_vars]
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    output$category1 <- renderUI({
      data.sel <- data.react()
      selectizeInput('cat1',
                     'Choose Cat 1',
                     choices = c("All", sort(as.character(
                       unique(data.sel$Category1)
                     ))),
                     selected = "All")
    })

    df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1, {
      data.sel <- data.react()
      if (input$cat1 == "All") {
        data.sel
      }
      else{
        data.sel[data.sel$Category1 == input$cat1,]
      }
    })

    output$category2 <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput(
        'cat2',
        'Choose Cat 2 (optional):',
        choices = sort(as.character(unique(
          df_subset()$Category2
        ))),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = NULL
      )
    })

    df_subset1 <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$cat2)) {
        df_subset()
      } else {
        df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2,]
      }
    })

    output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput(
        "size",
        label = "Size Range",
        min = min(data.input$Size),
        max = max(data.input$Size),
        value = c(min(data.input$Size), max(data.input$Size))
      )
    })

    df_subset2 <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$size)) {
        df_subset1()
      } else {
        df_subset1()[data.input$Size >= input$size[1] &
                       data.input$Size <= input$size[2],]
      }
    })
    output$table <- renderTable({
      df_subset2()

    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why do you use `renderUI` for input widgets?

Comment: Other people on this website have recommended using this one.

Comment: The problem is that you use `data.input$Size` to index `df_subset1()`, which has a different size. (`nrow(df_subset1()) != length(data.input$Size)`)

Comment: I solved your issue below.

Comment: Gregor is right on the money (only saw his answer after I finished typing my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of debugging, you'll notice that

```
df_subset2 <- reactive({
  if (is.null(input$size)) {
    df_subset1()
  } else {
    df_subset1()[data.input$Size >= input$size[1] &
                   data.input$Size <= input$size[2],]
  }
```

should be

```
df_subset2 <- reactive({
  if (is.null(input$size)) {
    df_subset1()
  } else {
    df_subset1()[df_subset1()$Size >= input$size[1] &
                  df_subset1()$Size <= input$size[2],]
  }
```

You were specifying the wrong condition to subset by in your conditional statement since you're referring to `data.input` **not** `data_subset1()`.

---

---

**A few other [less important] notes**

---

- **dplyr**

I would try replacing statements like the one below

```
df_subset1()[data.input$Size >= input$size[1] &
                   data.input$Size <= input$size[2],]
```

with

```
df_subset1()%>% filter(between(Size, input$size[1], input$size[2]))
```

because of readability. Many of your filtering conditions can be replaced via `filter()` within the package `dplyr`. It looks nicer.

---

- **Display of columns**

Please consider (this is only a suggestion, not that important)  replacing

```
selected = c("Category1", "Info", "Category2")
```

with

```
selected = c("Category1", "Info", "Category2", "Size")
```

for the initial display, in the UI, for debugging these kinds of things. It's kind of a pain to click back and forth when looking in the app. Why not have them all displayed at once?

I hope this helped!

Comment: Love the notes about `dplyr`! But doesn't your code break if `size` gets unselected in the `GUI`? You would have to do the column-filtering last I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your help and little attention. :)

Comment: Yes, the program was dropped using `dplyr`.

Comment: Gregor, that is a good point. It should break. Wouldn't the application break if `Category1` wasn't included as well, too? I'm pretty new to `reactive()` expressions (just learned them from within the OP).

Comment: Why do not the rows in the table show up when I not using the filter?

Comment: Which ones? The one I suggested to implement?

Comment: When I am changing only df_subset2 without the rest [less important] notes.

Comment: The rows don't show up on my end even if you don't use the `filter()` statement I recommended. I'm not sure why that's happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162054/discussion-between-infiniteflashchess-and-kim).